# How to extract a particular string by reading an XML file and store it in an another file using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, script, xml

I have an XML file content as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><testsuite errors="0" failures="0" name="pytest" skips="0" tests="4" time="38.586"/>
```

I want to get `errors="0" failures="0"` from this file and store it into another text file using shell script.

I tried using this `grep` but it's not working:

```
grep -r "errors.*.failures" file.xml
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The image is not very helpful. Could you please paste the text which it shows into your question?

Comment: This might be a good time to start learning to code Python:-)

Comment: You could look here for an answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83385/parse-xml-to-get-node-value-in-bash-script

Answer (score 0):

By default grep prints whole lines that contain a match. If the file is one single line you get the whole line, and so the whole file. Use `grep -o` to limit the output to what was matched.